# Fetching user data from Facebook on Xcode

Tags: xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fetch

I am trying to develop a simple app, which, retrieves data from Facebook, when the user connects to it.

After reading Facebook's example about how to retrieve User's photos and User's names, I just want to get information such as gender, city, e-mail, and date of birth, for example.

The following part, is where I got stuck:

```
- (void)populateUserDetails
{

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {


        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 self.userNameLabel.text = user.name;
                 self.userProfileImage.profileID = user.id;

             }
         }];

    }

}
```

My questions are:

- Should I make a dictionary with all this data? (gender, city, e-mail, etc.)
  -Also, I'm using the storyboard, can I use labels to all those data as Facebook's tutorial states, for the username?
- I read in a couple of places that the method requestForMe isn't the appropriate one for the other type of data I am looking for. What would be the method for my requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First you must ask user for permissions to access his gender, email, city ...**

You make a array with required permissions and add it to the **openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:** method

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown",@"user_location",@"email",@"basic_info", nil];

  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                     allowLoginUI:YES
                                completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                    FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                      }];
```

Then make a request like this to get informations you wanted

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"gender"]);
       NSLog(@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"hometown"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"birthday"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"email"]);
   }];
```

I hope i resolved your problem.

Comment: Hey Borbea, many thanks for your help. It resolved this issue. Also, for someone else who may have this issue, one of the things I was struggling with was that, I did not search correctly on FB's documentation, but with a bit more of a research I found the table which gives all fields the user Object can get. Here is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ . Once again, many thanks.